# Fragment Tabs Strange Crashes

Tags: java, android, xml

Does anyone know what to do with this Fragment Tabs Problem?

I am a very novice programmer with not much experience, especially in the world of Android application developing. I recently started a project with fragment tabs and I find that when I try to access a object (for lack of a better word, but I mean like a TextView, Spinner, EditText, etc.) by something like

```
TextView textBox = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.scouter_name_box);
```

the compiler finds no errors, but the app crashes. I have tried putting this line of code in a function, in the body of the fragment by itself (after onCreate()), and at the end of onCreate(). This doesn't help. The Error Log also doesn't say anything.

Furthermore, when I comment out this line, the rest of the app runs seamlessly. The app doesn't have any other activities except MainActivity and the three tab Fragments.

WHAT CAN I DO TO ACCESS THE TEXTVIEWS, SPINNERS, ETC?

also, as I mentioned I am very new. If you need a better explanation please ask, and sorry if I don't understand what you are saying at first.

We all have to start somewhere

Please help,
and Thank you in Advance

Tab XML File:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/input_scouter_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Scouter Name:"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Spinner android:id="@+id/choose_scouter_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/input_scouter_name"
        android:entries="@array/scouter_name_list" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity Java File:

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Declare Tab Variable

    Tab tab;
    ScoutingData ScoutData;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Create the actionbar
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        // Hide Actionbar Icon
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.red_and_blue_frisbees);

        // Hide Actionbar Title
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

        // Create Actionbar Tabs
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create Home Tab
        tab = actionBar.newTab().setTabListener(new FragmentsTab0());
        // Set Tab Title
        tab.setText("General");
        actionBar.addTab(tab);

        // Create first Tab
        tab = actionBar.newTab().setTabListener(new FragmentsTab1());
        // Set Tab Title
        tab.setText("Autonomous");
        actionBar.addTab(tab);

        // Create Second Tab
        tab = actionBar.newTab().setTabListener(new FragmentsTab2());
        // Set Tab Title
        tab.setText("Teleop");
        actionBar.addTab(tab);

        // Create Third Tab
        tab = actionBar.newTab().setTabListener(new FragmentsTab3());
        // Set Tab Title
        tab.setText("Endgame");
        actionBar.addTab(tab);
    }
}
```

Tab Java File:

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class FragmentsTab0 extends Fragment implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private Fragment mFragment;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from tab0fragment.xml
        getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.tab0fragment);
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mFragment = new FragmentsTab0();
        // Attach tab0fragment.xml layout
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment);
        ft.attach(mFragment);
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Remove tab0fragment.xml layout
        ft.remove(mFragment);
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    //Heeere's the Problem
    Spinner scouterName = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.choose_scouter_name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, remove `Spinner scoutername = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.choose_scouter_name)`. Secondly, remove `getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.tab0fragment);` from your `onCreate()`. You want to inflate your xml within `onCreateView` and then use that view to get the id of your other views. For example:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view;

        if (container == null) {

            return null;
        }

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab0fragment, container, false);
        Spinner scouterName = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.choose_scouter_name);
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming that I replace my onCreate() function with this new onCreateView() function? And also I got rid of the Spinner call in the body of the fragment after the other functions. I  imported all the new necessary items, but I still get an error that "nomap" (from R.layout.nomap) is not a field. Is there a fix or what can I replace this with? But thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes. Remove your onCreate() method and replace it with my onCreateView() method. And the error about nomap is my fault. I have updated the post with the proper code.

Comment: When I try this code, I get the error _"This method must return a result of type view"_. If it means anything, I have added my MainActivity code. But also, I notice that `if (container == null)` you return null. But the method is type View. Is it not supposed to return a View at any point? maybe after `view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab0fragment, container, false);` But anyway thanks for the help

Comment: @Live2Code sorry for the delayed response. You need to put `return view` at the end of the `onCreateView()` method.

Comment: I tried this, but problems occurred. The app opens to my activity_main.xml but then it "unexpectedly closes". it doesn't open the menu with the three tabs. I added my MainActivity() code to the problem description in my last post. Check it out for any problems. If you need my Manifest file or something, just ask. And as always, thank you for the help.

Comment: hello Mr Vartanian are you still there? I added a post after problems occurred again